# Android: Changing background of button in android

Tags: android, xml, button

Android: I am facing problem in changing background of buttons using xml in drawable folder in versions below 3.0. It resizes to small buttons in versions below 3.0. Should I change all my buttons to imageButtons, I have used many buttons in my app. Is there any solution for me?
I have attached my code below

```
<gradient android:startColor="#ffaaaa" android:centerColor="#ff0000" android:endColor="#ffaaaa" android:angle="90" />
<corners android:radius="15dp"/>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: what kind of problems?

Comment: what problems are you facing???what is your question??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by giving constant height and width for each button. Now it appears same like below versions of android 3.0 and also above it.

Answer (score 0):

What i understood is that you can not set background of ImageButton below android 3.0 right?

I had same problem before. so you have to set solid color to your own xml.

```
<gradient android:startColor="#ffaaaa" android:centerColor="#ff0000" android:endColor="#ffaaaa" android:angle="90" />
<solid android:color="00000000"/>
<corners android:radius="15dp"/>
```

please try above codes first.